# I was trying to make some walk animations for my mobs from the Roblox studio but I kept running into issues. How do I solve it?

Tags: animation, roblox

I kept on getting this error in my code and I dont know how to fix it. It is in Roblox Studio.
**Error**=Infinite yield possible on 'Workspace.Mobs.Soldier:WaitForChild("Animations")'
**Code**=   `` `local function animateMob(object)`
 `local humanoid = object:WaitForChild("Humanoid")`
 `local animationsFolder = object:WaitForChild("Animations")`

```
    ` if humanoid and animationsFolder then`
       ` local walkAnimation = animationsFolder:WaitForChild("Walk")`
       ` if walkAnimation then`
            `local animator = humanoid:FindFirstChild("Animator") or Instance.new("Animator", humanoid)`
            `local walkTrack = animator:LoadAnimation(walkAnimation)`
            `walkTrack:Load()`
            `walkTrack:Play()`
            `walkTrack.Looped=true`
        `end`
    `else`
        `warn("No humanoid/No animFolder for", object.Name)`
   ` end`
```

`end`

````
`workspace.Mobs.ChildAdded:Connect(animateMob)```
````

`
How do I fix the issue?

I tried to load and loop the walk track but to no avail

Comment: Can you show use where your `object` variable is coming from? The one you pass into the function as a parameter?